# Ruby on Rails 4 authentication, devise vs bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Ruby on Rails 4 and I started with the tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book and in this tutorial fo user's signup 'bcrypt' is used, however for my project I would like to have more options like email confirmation, password reset etc..So my question is, can I achieve all of this using existing rails 4 without any gems or do I need to use the 'devise' as suggested by some others in stack overflow. Also, can I use 'devise' gem along with 'bcrypt'?

Comment: i would go with devise, it gives you allot of options and its really easy to set up

Comment: any tutorial would you recommend?

Comment: @zigzag.bond  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise has step by step instructions on what to do so does this railscasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Short answer: **Devise isn't required**. You can write all the authentication / email confirmation / password reset logic yourself. There's nothing inherently 'magical' about Devise, it's just a well-written solution to a common problem.

However...

Writing a complete (and secure) authentication system isn't an easy task. I'd recommend working through the tutorial and letting it guide you through writing your own authentication system there.

Then you'll be in a better position to understand how web app authentication works and whether or not to use Devise.

FYI, Devise already uses `bcrypt`, as seen on its [gemspec](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.5.2/devise.gemspec#L23):

```
s.add_dependency("bcrypt-ruby", "~> 3.0")
```

Comment: Thank you for your time..I am ready to try devise, is there any step-by-setp tutorial would you recommend for the same??

Comment: @zigzag.bond [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages) has lots of how-tos for specific needs. [Rails Apps](http://railsapps.github.io/) has specific tutorials for integrating Devise.